# Python 2.4 plistlib on Linux

Tags: python, linux

According to http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html, plistlib is available to non-Mac platforms only since 2.6, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get it work on 2.4 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download it and give it a try:

http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/plistlib.py

(If that doesn't work, you may have more luck with the [2.4 version](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release24-maint/Lib/plat-mac/plistlib.py).)